# Aggregator and sorter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is it possible to use a sorter and and aggregator with two (group by) ports? I have done it with one (group by) port and succeeded, however when I add two group by ports, it fails stating that it was expecting an ascending port, the problem is my sorter already has both ports as ascending.

Comment: It should be working fine. Can you post a screenshot so it would be possible to review?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely sort and aggregate on multiple ports. Make sure the order of the ports in both the transformations are same.

Comment: Trying this again with the order the same